# Reading from a MongoDB changeStream with unbounded PCollections in Apache Beam

Tags: mongodb, architecture, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, data-warehouse

I'm designing a new way for my company to stream data from multiple MongoDB databases, perform some arbitrary initial transformations, and sink them into BigQuery.

There are various requirements but the key ones are speed and ability to omit or redact certain fields before they reach the data warehouse.

We're using Dataflow to basically do this:

`MongoDB -> Dataflow (Apache Beam, Python) -> BigQuery`

We basically need to just wait on the `collection.watch()` call as the input, but from the docs and existing research it may not be possible,

At the moment, the MongoDB connector is bounded and there seems to be no readily-available solution to read from a changeStream, or a collection in an unbounded way.

Is it possible to read from a changeStream and have the pipeline wait until the task is killed rather than being out of records?

Comment: The mongo db io connector in apache beam is bounded as you mentioned, both in Java and Python sdk. There is an opened ticket for supporting the streaming usecase of mongo db in Java https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2639.

Comment: For python sdk, currently there is no API support to write custom unbounded sources that's the main blocker for implementing your own solution to stream mongodb oplogs. For python streaming user of apache beam, cross language pipeline will be supported by the portability framework in the future which gives you capability to use a source class implemented in Java SDK to read data for your streaming pipeline.

Comment: @YichiZhang, Would you mind post your knowledge as an Answer for the sake of the community? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this instance I decided to go via Google Pub/Sub which serves as the unbounded data source.

Comment: @AlexFragotsis Listening on the changeStream and pushing to pubsub

Comment: yeah I mean did you ended up creating something like a microservice in order to listen for the change stream events or did you run the code as a dataflow job?

Comment: @AlexFragotsis You're correct - there is a microservice that pushes to pubsub (we do data scrubbing here). Pubsub is then consumed by a separate Dataflow job.